# How are Classes an Annotations Related in Java?

Tags: annotations

I found this quote

> the first step to using reflection is to obtain a Class object that
>   represents the class whose annotations you want to obtain

from Herbert Schildt

Can anyone explain that sentence and also "Class" with respect to annotations. Does an annotation reside inside a "Class" or not?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can add annotations to lots of symbols like classes, methods, constructors etc.

The point of the quote is, that in order to access those annotations at run-time, your entry point is the class object. From there you can start inspecting it, looking for methods, members etc. and access their annotations. This API is also called reflection, because it essentially reflects the code you have written as an object at run-time (including annotations).